# How to change database value if user's internet is switched off

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For the past few days i've been trying to show the online/offline status of a user.. For this i have a register activity where they register and their info gets saved in firebase and if they exit an activity i have overriden its onstop method and made the value to set to offline... but if the user suddenly loses internet connection it still shows online.. i cant change it to offline because internet is needed to make a change in the database and the use doesn't have internet... SO how do i set the database value to offline... i googled quite some stuff about this but didnt find anything... Can anyone please help me out please

My code

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    fetchData();
//        mDatabaseReference.child("UserData").child(UID).child("Online").setValue("True");
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    fetchData();
//        mDatabaseReference.child("UserData").child(UID).child("Online").setValue(false);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do is known as a presence system. The Firebase Database has a special API to allow this: `onDisconnect()`. When you attach a handler to `onDisconnect()`, the write operation you specify will be executed on the server when that server detects that the client has disconnected.

From the [documentation on managing presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence):

> Here is a simple example of writing data upon disconnection by using the `onDisconnect` primitive:
>
> ```
> DatabaseRef presenceRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("disconnectmessage");
> // Write a string when this client loses connection
> presenceRef.onDisconnect().setValue("I disconnected!");
> ```

In your case this could be as simple as:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    fetchData();
    DatabaseReference onlineRef = mDatabaseReference.child("UserData").child(UID).child("Online");
    onlineRef.setValue("True");
    onlineRef.onDisconnect().setValue("False");
}
```

Note that this will work in simple cases, but will start to have problems for example when your connection toggles rapidly. In that case it may take the server longer to detect that the client disappears (since this may depends on the socket timing out) than it takes the client to reconnect, resulting in an invalid `False`.

To handle these situations better, check out the [sample presence system in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample), which has more elaborate handling of edge cases.

Comment: onDisconnect i have used this earlier referring to some document... for me onDisconnect only works if the app is voluntarily closed(Not running in the background either) But my problem is what if the internet connection of the user goes off when he is online... i want it to change it to offline when this happens

Comment: The server can detect the disconnecting of a client in two ways:  1) When it's a clean disconnect (the app closes cleanly, it calls `goOffline()`, etc), the client sends a message to the server, which can then immediately execute the `onDisconnect()` handlers. 2) When it's a so-called dirty disconnect (you drive into a tunnel and lose signal, the app crashes, etc.), the server only detects that the client is gone once the socket ties out, which can take a few minutes. This is the expected behavior, and there is no better alternative that I know off.